# Most efficient array notation in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Using arrays as constant, what is more efficient:

```
array[1,2,3]
```

or

```
'{1,2,3}'::int[]`
```

?

Or, more complex:

```
array['1812-01-01'::date, '1812-02-02']
```

or

```
'{1812-01-01,1812-02-02}'::date[]
```

?

I really scare to dip to the PostgreSQL sources despite the fact that it is wonderful.

**Update**

Partial answer, based on the investigation provided by @VaoTsun (thanks a lot!) Surprisingly `'{1,2,3}'::int[]` is faster then `array[1,2,3]`. Dixi!

Comment: Efficient computation-wise? They don't define one as being more efficient. If there's a significant difference, which btw I doubt, it's subject to change in later versions.

Comment: @sudo It was "minds on the road"... In particular, what you prefer: `'{1,2}::int[]'` or `array[1,2]` and why?

Comment: ...Why don't you just try it yourself?

Comment: @NickBarnes Because I'm too stupid to come up with a test where it would be more significant then the measurement error. It means that it is no big difference between two ways of array notations but honestly it is theoretical question. Just curios.

Comment: As all those expressions are converted at **parse time** they have no influence whatsoever on the run time of a query. So I don't think this is of any importance.

Comment: @Abelisto but you can compare results statistically with big nambers, to measure the measurement error itself. I tried 10 loops to see that for all 10 `array[` is slightly slower - you can try 10K times - if rate remains, I think you can expect its not just a measurement error.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, but I imagine two parsing stages: while `array[1,2,3]` could be parsed at the first stage `'{1,2,3}::int[]'` could needed to be parsed at the second one, like "parse the entire query, then parse (and convert) strings to given types"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on my machine the `array[]` is always slightly slower then `'{}'` one:

```
so=# do $$
declare
 t text;
 ts timestamptz;
begin
 for n in 1..10 loop
  select clock_timestamp() into ts;
  for i in 1..99999 loop
   execute format($f$select array['18%s-01-01'::date, '18%s-02-02']$f$,i,i) into t;
  end loop;
  raise info '%', t||' "[" '||clock_timestamp() - ts;

  select clock_timestamp() into ts;
  for i in 1..99999 loop
   execute format($f$select '{18%s-01-01,18%s-02-02}'::date[]$f$,i,i) into t;
  end loop;
  raise info '%', t||' "{" '||clock_timestamp() - ts;
 end loop;
end; $$;
INFO:  {1899999-01-01,1899999-02-02} "[" 00:00:01.99259
INFO:  {1899999-01-01,1899999-02-02} "{" 00:00:01.691473
INFO:  {1899999-01-01,1899999-02-02} "[" 00:00:02.207583
INFO:  {1899999-01-01,1899999-02-02} "{" 00:00:01.762358
INFO:  {1899999-01-01,1899999-02-02} "[" 00:00:01.926091
INFO:  {1899999-01-01,1899999-02-02} "{" 00:00:01.685358
INFO:  {1899999-01-01,1899999-02-02} "[" 00:00:01.98542
INFO:  {1899999-01-01,1899999-02-02} "{" 00:00:01.686831
INFO:  {1899999-01-01,1899999-02-02} "[" 00:00:02.01972
INFO:  {1899999-01-01,1899999-02-02} "{" 00:00:01.698365
INFO:  {1899999-01-01,1899999-02-02} "[" 00:00:02.008609
INFO:  {1899999-01-01,1899999-02-02} "{" 00:00:01.698494
INFO:  {1899999-01-01,1899999-02-02} "[" 00:00:01.987951
INFO:  {1899999-01-01,1899999-02-02} "{" 00:00:01.698711
INFO:  {1899999-01-01,1899999-02-02} "[" 00:00:01.977347
INFO:  {1899999-01-01,1899999-02-02} "{" 00:00:01.707921
INFO:  {1899999-01-01,1899999-02-02} "[" 00:00:01.945438
INFO:  {1899999-01-01,1899999-02-02} "{" 00:00:01.663771
INFO:  {1899999-01-01,1899999-02-02} "[" 00:00:02.079186
INFO:  {1899999-01-01,1899999-02-02} "{" 00:00:01.752366
DO
Time: 37178.056 ms
```

Implicitly docs suggest the"curly" way to introduce arrays in the first line:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT

> To write an array value as a literal constant, enclose the element
>   values within curly braces and separate them by commas.

And later:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS

> An array constructor is an expression that builds an array value using
>   values for its member elements.

So you can expect building the curly values from array construct to take additional tick. But surely I'm just speculating here. The answer was meant only to measure linear impact of both ways mixed close in time on no load PC...

Also `IN (scalar list)` is rewritten to `= ANY(array)` construct in "curly" format:

```
so=# explain analyse select * from pg_database where datname in ('t','so');
                                              QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on pg_database  (cost=0.00..1.02 rows=2 width=254) (actual time=0.105..0.109 rows=2 loops=1)
   Filter: (datname = ANY ('{t,so}'::name[]))
```

I'm not saying it's an implication to do same, but it looks internally chosen way over `array[` construct, so might be a hint

Comment: I am really surprised. Coming from the compilable language like C/Pascal I was sure that "ready to use" forms like `array[...]` are faster then forms that needs additional parsing like `'{1,2,3}'`. But nope. Second one is about 5 times faster then first one for some reasons (https://pastebin.com/0jTdvPph)[https://pastebin.com/0jTdvPph]. Just interesting: why?

Comment: I did not look into the code, so I'm speculating in docs here. the `array[` construct is not ready to use, but to be first used to build `'{`value and then parsed. I'm afraid looking into the source is unavoidable here :)

Comment: Ok, thats it. Previously I preferred to use `array[...]` and for now I know why my queries was so slow :)

Comment: happy you, I wish I'd find my golden little key :)

Comment: It will be at the end of everything >:-E Be patient ;) And good luck of course!